# OrderBy an INT Column in LINQ to Entities using dynamic Expression in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm having a tables Namely **`StudentInfo`**

Table: `DbSet<StudentInfo>`

```
ID    Name
_____________________
1     Ram
2     Kumar
```

My C# Code is

```
using(var db = new Entities()) {

    Expression<Func<StudentInfo,object>> sortColumn = i => i.ID;

    IQueryable<StudentInfo> qryStudent = db.StudentInfos.Where(i => true)
                                                 .OrderBy(sortColumn);
}
```

Its throwing an Exception

> "Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ
>   to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

If I modify the code like `i => i.ID.ToString()` in Expression, its working

```
using(var db = new Entities()) {

    Expression<Func<StudentInfo,object>> sortColumn = i => i.ID.ToString();

    IQueryable<StudentInfo> qryStudent = db.StudentInfos.Where(i => true)
                                                 .OrderBy(sortColumn);
}
```

How to fix this in a right way.

I need a generic solution, the Expression should be `Expression<Func<StudentInfo,dynamic>>` like this. It should match for both

```
switch(sortKey) {
    case "ID"
        sortColumn = i => i.ID;
        break;
    case "Name"
        sortColumn = i => i.Name;
        break;
}
```

Kindly assist me...

Comment: Does it work if you change `Expression<Func<StudentInfo,object>>` to `Expression<Func<StudentInfo,int>>`?

Answer (score 1):

There are some points to be considered:

- `Where(i => true)` simply takes all elements, wich is not necessary
- Why do you use the string value of your id? if it's an integer, you can change the expression to the following:
  `Expression<Func<StudentInfo, int>> sortColumn = i => i.ID;`

Please try to describe your complete problem. So it's easier to answer and you probably get help much faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following code:

```
Expression<Func<StudentInfo, object>> sortColumn = i => Convert.ToInt32(i.ID);
```

Problem is while converting object type of data to integer type.

Comment: Its throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the IQueryable to add a custom OrderBy which takes the sort key like this

```
    public static IQueryable OrderBy(this IQueryable<StudentInfo> queryable, string sortKey)
    {
        switch (sortKey)
        {
            case "ID":
                return queryable.OrderBy(i => i.ID);
            case "Name":
                return queryable.OrderBy(i => i.Name);
        }

        return queryable;
    }
```

With this you can do an order by using your sort key like this

```
    var students = db.StudentInfos.OrderBy(sortColumn, "ID");
```

Comment: I believe that last line should be `var students = db.StudentInfos.OrderBy("ID");`  or   `var students = db.StudentInfos.OrderBy(sortKey);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from github https://github.com/PoweredSoft/DynamicLinq

Or Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/PoweredSoft.DynamicLinq/

Simple Sorting

```
query = query.OrderByDescending("AuthorId");
query = query.ThenBy("Id");
```